# Is it possible to search a column of IDs for 1 if other rows include IDs with 1 in them?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with a varchar column (although the column type can be changed if needed).

The column stores some ids separated with underscores like so:

Row 1: 1

Row 2: 1_2_3

Row 3: 10_2

Row 4: 4_5_1

Is there anyway in this structure to query that column for 1 and return all rows with 1 (but not Row 3 which contains 1 but the ID is 10).

To get the current results I am attempting to search the column `LIKE %1%`.

Or do I need to change the structure to achieve the result I want?

Comment: share sample data and its expected output

Comment: Storing lists of values separated by a delimiter is an antipattern. See Chaprter 2 of Bill Karwin's book https://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the operator [`like`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

```
select * from tablename
where concat('_', id, '_') like '%@_1@_%' escape '@'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/agsfKd1mkvCNPTjW1sixfe/1).
Results:

```
| id    |
| ----- |
| 1     |
| 1_2_3 |
| 4_5_1 |
```

Comment: Thanks can either of you foresee any issues with using this? would it always return what I have described, I'm trying to think of any issues with combinations of other numbers.

Comment: If the id is exactly as you describe it then this will work. But better, try it.

Comment: The underscore is a special char when used with the like operator. The escape means that the char after @ which is the underscore should be treated as a regular char and not like a special char.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try:

```
select *
from t
where c like '1\_%'
   or c like '%\_1'
   or c like '%\_1\_%'
   or c = '1'
```

You need to escape the underscore as `\_`, since SQL defines it as a wildcard and will match any character.

Comment: Thanks, as you were making the edits to this I was trying it and debugging as I went, the last step was to get the value for 1 on it's own that you've just added. I am just going to try out the other answer to see if it returns the same results and then decide which to implement - is there any factors I should be aware of to using either query (this one or the one by @forpas)?

Comment: To wit: they'll both scan the entire table.

Answer (score 2):

If we had a comma separator, then we could use MySQL `FIND_IN_SET` function.

We can use MySQL `REPLACE` function to change the underscores to commas,

e.g.

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM t 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1',REPLACE( t.id ,'_',','))
```

Reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

---

**NOTE:**

Storing underscore separated lists is an antipattern. See Chapter 2 of Bill Karwin's book "SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming"

[https://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557)